# Computer Speakers vs. Human Voice

Tags: audio, frequency, speakers, sound

How do computer speakers compare to the human voice in regards to the range of frequencies they can produce?
What is the lowest a human voice can go (either world record or just the average person) and how high?
Likewise, what are the lower and upper limits for a computer? Any model of computer should serve as a good example.
What devices currently most effectively mimic the human voice in volume range and frequency range?

Comment: This is an under defined question. A computer with a good sound card or DAC and thousand dollar studio monitors can play way more than your voice can, like an orchestra.

Comment: why are you asking about the range of human voice? ... simple google search should result in an answer

Comment: since speakers are produced that can produce sounds only heard by dogs etc then they exceed our capabilities.

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

'Computer Speakers' is not a specification. Some desktop computers have a tiny speaker built in, for reproducing beeps. Laptops attempt a better frequency response. Most people would think of computer speakers as those you plug in, which can reach a reasonable hifi frequency range.

You can get intelligible voice over the telephony bandwidth of 300 to 3400 Hz, though it will sound like it's coming through a telephone.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking just about the range of frequencies, the answer is simple; voice frequency is capped at about 4kHz (more with harmonics), while for computers it all depends on how much power do you want to dedicate to the task… consumer audio these days can go up to 96kHz, and there are converters going up to RF so for audio there is no practical limit.

If you however need to compare the *quality* of the signal, then more than the converter itself you will need to work on the transducers (speakers and microphones); these are the bottlenecks in modern audio chains.